# Is the keyCode always the same for every device?

Tags: java-me, device, lwuit, smartphone, mobile-devices

I want to catch the **delete** event inside a `TextField`. So I thought about the `keyReleased` method which contains the `keyCode` param.

Is the `keyCode` value always the same for all mobile phones ? I found that it is -8 ( delete ) on the emulator.